# How to find or reset pwd in Developer for KDB

Tags: kdb

I'm running a free version of KDB on my local machine and installed Developer to check if this is something I wanted to start using.

I created a workspace/repository with just a basic username/pwd connecting to it via localhost:port/ax/

However, as I was just checking things out, i.e. it was meant to be very temporary, I have now promptly forgotten my user’s password over the Christmas break. I know, capital mistake.

Is there a way to reset the password for the user I created or find it somehow? I know I can read the code files from the repository under developer/workspace//, but I had some things on my scratchpad that I'd like to keep and I'd prefer to avoid the copy and paste however benign.

KDB version: 3.6

Developer version: 1.5.1

Comment: This sounds more like a Developer product issue rather than a pure kdb issue - you may be better off asking on the product forum of https://community.kx.com/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about that forum so that helps!